# Merit Gem: How to expire cached values?

Tags: caching, merit-gem

I'm trying to cache User data, but find that points generated by the Merit gem aren't being expired properly. Normally I could do something like this in Rails:

```
belongs_to :user, touch: true
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with Merit so that cached scores expire when changed?

Answer (score 0):

In merit [there's points, scores, and a sash model](https://github.com/tute/merit/wiki/General-merit-workflow#models-diagram--150) before the user, and they don't have any `touch` logic in it's models yet (a good feature request by the way). So there's no way as of version 1.7.0.